# java.lang.NullPointerException: null on a list that existed in database

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller

So here's my code

**Controller**

```java
@GetMapping("/faskes/tambah")
public String addFaskesForm(Model model){
    List<VaksinModel> listVaksin = vaksinService.getVaksinList();
    model.addAttribute("faskes", new FaskesModel());
    model.addAttribute("listVaksin", listVaksin);
    return "form-add-faskes";
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<select name="vaksin" >
  <option th:each="vaksin : ${listVaksin}"
    th:value="${vaksin.idVaksin}"
    th:text="${vaksin.jenisVaksin}">
  </option>
</select>
```

The listVaksin is found to be null. Can someone point out my mistake? thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you show some more code, like the service? And a full stack trace?